# htaccess redirect 1 domain to http, others to https. all for non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite

I use htaccess to load Magento websites.
the problem is that I have 1 domain without SSL, is it possible to redirect just this 1 domain to http, while any others will be redirected to https. All domains should point to non-www version.

My current htaacces:

```
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*abc\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:abc]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*abc\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*qwe\.de [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:qwe]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*qwe\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*zxc\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:zxc]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*zxc\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

I like qwe.de to be redirected to http. while any other domain should point to https.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the htaccess not with magento

Try with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^metrikstudios\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Hi, question was about redirecting to http from https. you answered with opposite thing.